# Simulating mouse wheel without move the mouse

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to simulate the mouse wheel up/down using the `PostMessage()`

```
PostMessage(Handle, Msg, wParam, lParam);
PostMessage(Handle, 0x20A, 0xFF880000, lpara);
```

These values I got using Spy++, the lparam is created using the X Y coordinate.

So, here is my problem... When I try to simulate it in a window that I can scroll up/down, it only works if I move the mouse in the position of the scroll, the window doesn't need to be at the top/in focus, but the mouse must be at that position.

But the problem is that I need to simulate it without move the cursor itself, maybe with a "fake" movement or whatever.

Someone knows how to do that without move the mouse?

Comment: Why bother with mouse wheel messages? Why don't you send WM_VSCROLL messages?

Comment: I tried, but the Handle is the while window and the part that I want to scroll is just in a part of that, I can't get only the handle of the scroll or that part to scroll. The examples that I found using the WM_VSCROLL needs this scroll handle value.

Comment: The message is sent, not posted.

Comment: But the Handle still not possible, I mean, I can't get the handle of only that part of the scroll bar, just the whole window, how am I suppost to simulate it in that XY window position?